Centered Subgaussian Variables have better Properties
I am trying to understand the following proof:




Main Confusion: In particular, I am having a very hard time understanding the chain of inequalities in the proof for (3)': I think the first equality is due to $X$ being symmetric. However, how did we obtain the rest of the inequalities? Could someone expand and explain the details behind these inequalities?

I think the last inequality requires some additional information. Perhaps, it is part of the proof of (1) implies (2).

@geetha290krm I have updated the post for the previous proofs.
